# How can I fix my OpenCV4 installation on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, makefile

I need some help. I want to install Opencv4 on my computer (which runs on Ubuntu) and use it with VSCode.

A lot of tutorial explains how to do it, so here is one of thoses I followed: https://vitux.com/opencv_ubuntu/

I, next, took a program my teacher sent me to check installation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string imageName("/home/baptiste/Documents/M1/infographie/images/lena.jpg"); // path to the image

    Mat img;
    img = imread(imageName, IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file as a color image
    if( img.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat img_gray;

    img_gray = imread(imageName,IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); //Read the file as a grayscale image
    if( img_gray.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    imshow( "Image read", img );                // Show our color image inside the window.

    imshow("Grayscale image read", img_gray); //Show our grayscale image inside the window.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    imwrite("/home/baptiste/Documents/M1/infographie/images/lena_gray.jpg", img_gray); //Save our grayscale image into the file
    return 0;
}
```

I also wrote a makefile:

```
CC=g++

read_image: read_image.cpp
    $(CC) read_image.cpp -o read_image `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4`

clean:
    rm -f read_image
```

But when I am compiling, I got this:

```
g++ read_image.cpp -o read_image `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4`
In file included from read_image.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp:46:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
   46 | #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:4 : read_image] Erreur 1
```

I also spot a problem with my opencv installation: in /usr/local/include, I have a *opencv4* folder, which contains...a *opencv2* folder, and then the whole installation.

I am interpreting this as: the inclusion made by the modules are not reading at the good place. My program actually recognize the location of *highgui.hpp*, but that module does not recognize the good location for *core.hpp*

I did not saw anyone having that problem so it might be quite weird but can someone help me with that ?

Also, I added `"/usr/local/include/opencv4/**"` into my VSCode configuration.

Thank you for your answer, and for the time you will invest.

EDIT 1:
Here is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And how do I the "tasks.json" file ?

Comment: File is in the question, I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am interpreting this as: the inclusion made by the modules are not reading at the good place. My program actually recognize the location of highgui.hpp, but that module does not recognize the good location for core.hpp

nice & correct analysis, for a noob !!

your teacher's test program is already incorrect

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

should be:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>      // added for clarity
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp> // same
```

and you should probably drop the (opaque and badly supported) `pkg-config` parts from your makefile, and add paths / libs manually, so you at least "know, what you're doing":

```
CC=g++
INC=/usr/local/include/opencv4
LIB=/usr/local/lib
LIBS=-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs
read_image: read_image.cpp
    $(CC) -I$(INC) read_image.cpp -o read_image -L$(LIB) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f read_image
```

Comment: I would appreciate no judgment. I am still a student, and I had to modify the file so it can launch without direct compiler errors. Yet I still have errors and I am woming here because I need help, not because I want people to laugh at me.

I will test your solution.

Comment: Ok so thanks to a still entire mystery, it worked. Could you explain me how did it work ?

Comment: "Could you explain me how did it work ?" -- old school knowledge about g++/makefiles, i guess. and i have to add, that usually adding complicated tools like pkg-config or vscode makes it only worse ...